# Typescript error condition will always return 'true' since the types 'string' and '0' have no overlap

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to convert a javascript number to words converter to typescript type once i done the conversion. I am seeing a error in below block

> This condition will always return 'true' since the types 'string' and '0' have no overlap.

```
export const inWords = (num: any) => {
  if ((num = num.toString()).length > 9) return 'overflow';
  const n = ('000000000' + num).substr(-9).match(/^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{1})(\d{2})$/);
  if (!n) return;
  let str = '';
  str += n[1] !== 0 ? (a[Number(n[1])] || b[n[1][0]] + ' ' + a[n[1][1]]) + 'crore ' : '';
  str += n[2] !== 0 ? (a[Number(n[2])] || b[n[2][0]] + ' ' + a[n[2][1]]) + 'lakh ' : '';
  str += n[3] !== 0 ? (a[Number(n[3])] || b[n[3][0]] + ' ' + a[n[3][1]]) + 'thousand ' : '';
  str += n[4] !== 0 ? (a[Number(n[4])] || b[n[4][0]] + ' ' + a[n[4][1]]) + 'hundred ' : '';
  str +=
    n[5] !== 0
      ? (str !== '' ? 'and ' : '') + (a[Number(n[5])] || b[n[5][0]] + ' ' + a[n[5][1]]) + 'only '
      : '';
  return str;
};
```

I don't have a clue about this error

Comment: n[1] !== 0, should be n[1] !== "0"

Answer (score 0):

const n only contains strings, even if num is a number, since you are concatenating on line 3

```
const n = ('000000000' + num)
```

In your ternary expressions, you are doing a strong type assertion (!==) which will check not only the value, but also the type.

Since your value is always a string, it will always be different from a number